# App crashes with BLE under Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a Swift App using Bluetooth LE, that crashes from time to time - not really reproducable.

I get always the same error message but can't find anything to lighten things up.

> *** Assertion failure in -[CBUUID initWithData:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth-327.1/CBUUID.m:170
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Data <> does not
>   represent a valid UUID'

Does anybody has a idea what the error might be?

Thanks in advance

Reto

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is. As far as the cause, you need to do some more debugging and/or make your code more resilient. If data is empty, too short or too long you shouldn't attempt to turn it into a CBUUID. Can you show the code where you are doing this. Where does the data come from?

Comment: I do not actively turn data into a CBUUID. Actually I do not use a CBUUID instance in the whole project. It must be initiated by another method. If you know where it could be initiated it would be very helpful...

The data should come from an BLE peripheral. 

Thanks

Comment: You need to look at the stack trace to try and see where the call was made or perhaps you have a problem with your peripheral

Comment: Hi Paul! What do you mean with "problem with your peripheral"? Is is custom made hardware, so do you think it is possible that the hardware doesn't send proper data?

Comment: The error need you to valid data is a valid uuid format. I don't see a official case to validate it.